# How to properly export a VB.NET Windows Appliction as EXE?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I would like to export a .NET Windows application as `exe`. I would normally pick up the EXE file from the `bin\Debug` folder and run directly in the development machine. In this case, the application doesn't show any error.

But when I copy the same `.exe` to another machine and try to run the application, I get the following error. Can somebody help me to identify what I'm missing here?

[image: Error]

I'm very new to .NET Windows applications.

Comment: It looks like you need to install crystal reports on that machine. You should lookup how to create an installer that will automatically install program dependencies (like crystal reports).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your application has dependencies on third party assemblies that have not been deployed to the target machine. You must make sure that you deploy those third party dependencies on any machine that runs your program. Your program works on your development machine because you have, presumably, installed the necessary assemblies when you installed the dev tools for the third party product.

The error message indicates that you application has a dependency on Crystal Reports. So you probably need to deploy the Crystal Reports redistributable package. Once you've cleared that up, there may be other dependencies to resolve.

Comment: Yeah, I was missing few packages. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

wrap a try .... catch around the problematic code, and run through it , find out why its throwing the error then from there post another question / or edit yours, i believe that is the better way to go. - it will tell you in way more detail then that error what went wrong, and most likely why.

Comment: Will use your technique in my future projects. Thank you.